# React Native force component refresh when the app goes to foreground

Tags: react-native, accessibility, react-hooks, react-native-device-info, font-scaling

My app displays some Texts. I need to re-render a `Component` when the font size changes via Settings --> Accessibility --> Font size:

[image]

So basically this is se sequence:

- The app is opened (foreground).
- The user opens the Phone Settings so the app goes to foreground (not completely closed).
- The user changes the Font size via via Settings --> Accessibility -->
  Font size.
- The user closes the Settings and opens the app goes to foreground
  again.

At this point I need to reload the app because some `Components` need to be adapted.

I'm using [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info) to get the font size using `const fontScale = DeviceInfo.getFontScale();` but its value doesn't get updated until the app is completely closed and opened.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `appstate` to `nextAppState`. It should cause the component to rerender.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppState, Text} from 'react-native';

class AppStateExample extends Component {
  state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (
      this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      nextAppState === 'active'
    ) {
      console.log('App has come to the foreground!');
    }
    this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  };

  render() {
    return <Text>Current state is: {this.state.appState}</Text>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would it be possible to implementing using hooks? I'm quite new on React and my project uses hooks

Comment: I havn't dived much deeper into hooks, but only takes few mins of research to convert such a simple component into a functional component using `hooks`. What I currently use is `recomposeJS`

Comment: I always get the error "Cant perform a React state update on an unmounted component" whenever I use setState in the appStateChange event handler. Any idea why?